# Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which consists:

```
source  dest  euclidean
 A       B       0.5
 A       C       1.5
 A       D       0.5
 A       E       0.8
 B       C       0.5
 B       D       6.5
 B       E       5.4
 B       A       4.8
 C       B       4.3
 C       D       3.6
 C       E       2.6
 C       A       3.5
 D       B       8.0
 D       C       2.7
 D       E       7.7
 D       A       7.3
```

I want to find Minimum Spanning Tree Which connects these points, where the weights edges are euclidean distance.

I tried using a method shown in [Geeks for geeks EMST](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-2-kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/) :

```
g = Graph(4)
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  g.addEdge(row['source'],row['dest'],row['euclidean'])

g.KruskalMST()
```

But it gave an error.

Is there any other way I Can find this? Any leads will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.mst.html), you can use

```
from networkx import *

g = Graph()
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  g.add_edge(row['source'],row['dest'],weight=row['euclidean'])

>>> list(minimum_spanning_edges(g))
[('A', 'E', {'weight': 0.8}),
 ('C', 'E', {'weight': 2.6}),
 ('C', 'D', {'weight': 2.7}),
 ('B', 'C', {'weight': 4.3})]
```

Comment: But how do i specify euclidean weights for every vertex?

Comment: @Shubham You mean edge, no? it's not a property of vertexes. See update.

Comment: Did you mean `g=nx.cycle_graph()` In your first line ? Because i get error as  `name Graph` not defined

Comment: @Shubham Added the import; note it assumes you installed networkx.

Comment: @ Ami , yes, Testing it now. This was a sample data i posted, i actually have around 1000 vertex :p

Comment: @Shubham I was actually wrong a bit - if it's `from networkx import *`, then it shouldn't be `nx.minimum_spanning_edges`. BTW, 1000 vertexes isn't large in itself - the question is whether the graph is sparse or not. In any case, it doesn't sound like a huge problem.